# Convert all entries in a pandas (list) to just first entry of list

Tags: pandas, split, series

I have a pandas series like so:

```
df = pd.Series(
    [['abc', 'xyz1'],
    ['abc', 'xyz1'],
    ['def', 'xyz1'],
    ['def', 'xyz1']]
)
```

I'd like to convert so that there are no more lists, and only the first entry from each list:

```
df = pd.Series('abc', 'abc', 'def', 'def')
```

Any ideas?

Actually this was the result of a dataframe:

```
temp = df_original["Col1"].str.split("/", n=1)
```

I wanted in this line to already split and extract the first string (I tried `[0]` at the end - didn't work). Then I tried:

```
temp_1 = temp.map(lambda x: x[0])
```

But still didn't work.

Comment: Because already splitted column use `print (df.map(lambda x: x[0]))` or `print (df.str[0])`

Comment: @jezrael I tried this link and still got an error: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable: I saw the other post, that's why I did my post.

Comment: it means there are some missing values, so need `print (df.str[0]) `

Comment: @jezrael Actually the .str[0] at the end did the trick, thanks!